# EurekaLog analog for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, eurekalog

Delphi developers remember the awesome tool called EurekaLog, it is nice exception reporting tool that integrates into the application. The question is addressed to the .NET developers who are using Visual Studio - is there the same tool like EurekaLog but for .NET development? Any alternatives?

Comment: Speaking about leaks, Deleaker now supports Delphi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suyJfoSeRrQ